# How to hide/show content when checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a form for a client and he has given me the task to create a show/hide effect when certain checkbox in unselected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should do it:

```
$("#yourCheckboxID").click(function ()
{
    if ($("#yourCheckboxID").attr("checked"))
    {
        $("#yourDivID").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#yourDivID").hide();
    }              
});
```

It will hide or show a specific `div` based on a `checkbox`.  I wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to hide or show so I just assumed a `div`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#checkboxID").change(function() { $("#targetToHideAndShow").toggle() } );
```

Comment: This has the drawback that initially upon page load, `#targetToHideAndShow` will always be shown, not hidden.