# Show or hide a field using jQuery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I want to know how to show the date field on a form after a click(select) on the check box and hide it after unselecting it. Below is the screenshot. - Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you try with jquery documentation? It's easy and examples are very useful and sample. Try with research effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide/show content when checkbox is checked/unchecked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104405/how-to-hide-show-content-when-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<label for="chkEle">Check This</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkEle" />
<div id="divEle" style="display:none;"><date stuff></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input[name=chkEle]").change(function(e) {
    $("#divEle").toggle();
});
```

.change is triggered even if the label is clicked instead of the checkbox. This also allows you to dynamically make change in js later.  For instance if you wanted to force the checkbox selection on page load, then at the end of you code you could add `$("input[name=chkEle]").change();` and that would trigger the change both on the back end and visually

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the selectors with whatever your appropriate ones are:

```
$('checkbox_selector').click(function ()
{
    $('date_field_selector').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I think he means show & hide the text inside the date field, not the actual field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkBox').click(function() {
    $('#dateBox')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem as it defeats the purpose of having a checkbox upon which he could later check the state in order to preform more functions.  Plus, this could cause visual errors (as I have found) in that a user can click a a checkbox label and have no effect on the checkbox itself, whereas using .change is affected even if a label is clicked instead of the actual checkbox