# Toggle check/uncheck for multiple checkbox lists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have two problems with checking and unchecking (select and deselect all) a checkboxlist:

1. The parent checkbox does not check/uncheck.
2. I need to only select the children.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/v6wmV/,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.all').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.check').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.check').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
        });
});
```

Right now, I have the event on a class, and since the class is shared by both checkbox lists, they all toggle.

Comment: check my answer to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246150/show-or-hide-a-field-using-jquery-or-ajax/9246161#9246161

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v6wmV/177/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.all').click(function() {
        var $checkboxes = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]');
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });     
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="all" /> Check/Uncheck all<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 1<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 2<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 3<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 4<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 5<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 6<br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> 7
</div>
...
```

Comment: this definitely works but you do NOT need the "? true : false" part, since "$(this).is(':checked')" already returns true or false.
it's like saying "if(true){ true } else { false}"

Comment: Actually, it needs a !$(this).is('checked'), otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Nice post above. Yet another way using each function, though its not using the children only.

```js
jQuery('.check-all').click(function() {
      jQuery('.checked-rec').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', $('.check-all').is(':checked'));
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check-all">
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checked-rec">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checked-rec">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checked-rec">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checked-rec">
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```