# How to hide/show part of a form when checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html

**[I found a solution right here, works perfectly!](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Hide-DIV-with-TextBox-when-CheckBox-is-checked-unchecked-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx)**

This is my first attempt of trying to hide and show a section of a form with javascript. I have 0 experience with javascript and tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbm1qXCAWjI) and [this basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104405/how-to-hide-show-content-when-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked) on top of several other websites and tutorials over the last 2-3 hours, yet all fails to actually work.

I made a form with several radio's, a few text fields and a several checkboxes. I want some of these text fields to be invisible until you check a specific checkbox that will show them. I'd like to do this to several checkboxes for several text fields.

Example: You check the checkbox "Other" and a textfield appears to tell you to specify other in that field.

I narrowed my code down to just a small test below, since I do not wish to share all questions and wanted a simple way to figure out how to get it to work. I put the to be hiden/shown section in a `div` because I thought that might help it, according to the "basic exmaple", but it is not necessary to be in a `div` for my form.

Thank you in advance for your reply and apologies for my noobness :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
$("#yourCheckboxID").click(function ()
{
    if ($("#boxchecked").attr("checked"))
    {
        $("#hidden").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#hidden").hide();
    }              
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="box" />
      Main.</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="boxchecked" />
      Other.</label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="hidden">Can you see this?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are calling elements doesn't exists where is divshow and yourCheckBoxId element? Add to your script a document.onReady because you are setting the click event before the page is full loaded.

Comment: As stated, I am am a noob and have no idea what you just mentioned. I did saw that in the code I posted I accidentally wrote "divshow" instead of "hidden", which I had wrong in just this post :) Oops!

Comment: The checkbox ID is at the end of the label.

Comment: I don't see this id (#boxchecked) anywhere.

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="box" />
      Main.</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="boxchecked" /> RIGHT HERE!
      Other.</label>
    <br />

Comment: @manuerumx solution worked in the end. Thanks for all your help and being pantient :) Good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using the prop function from jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#boxchecked").click(function (){
            if ($("#boxchecked").prop("checked")){
                $("#hidden").hide();
            }else{
                $("#hidden").show();
            }              
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to add extra code for jQuery for that to work?

Comment: Nop, only the reference to jQuery library

Comment: Does not seem to work either. [See here](http://truedragonblood.ucoz.com/test2.html)

Comment: Ah, I will have to make that reference then :)

Comment: You need to add before the script tag the reference to jQuery. <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

Comment: Still not working, I either must be horrible or my google chrome is trolling me.

Comment: If is the page http://truedragonblood.ucoz.com/test2.html, still missing the jQuery reference

Comment: I did not update the link but tried on my own device :) [here you go](http://truedragonblood.ucoz.com/test2.html)

Comment: It works! Thank you! I can't say how happy I am to see it actually do something! Well, sort off. How to keep it hidden when you first look at the page?

Comment: With CSS styles. #hidden {display:none}

Comment: I will do that, thank you so much :) The frustration was getting real.

Comment: Hello Manuerumx. I've been working on the form again today and found out your method does not work in IE. It also shows after you uncheck the box after checking it, not on the first initial check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to achieve this, use psuedo selectors:

```css
.inputs {
  display: none;
}

.foo:checked + .inputs {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<form action="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" class="foo">
  <div class="inputs">
    bla blah inputs
    <input type="text">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: True, but is asking with jQuery.

Comment: How am I supposed to link it to my 'div' or text and textfield? I do not think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Elvalianon The second selector in my css explains that. Any "foo" input that is checked will put the display property on any element that has the class "bar" to `initial`. You can of course use another class, or even an id.

Comment: @Elvalianon See my edit, I've added a container for the inputs and a textarea.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out :)

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I tried your method as well and it works great as it is. However if I add any code after it all stops responding and there are two textfields showing of which I have 0 control over.

Comment: @Elvalianon Make sure you don't have any infinite loops in your javascript, those can cause your browser to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#boxchecked").is(':checked')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#boxchecked").click(function ()
  {
      if ($("#boxchecked").is(':checked'))
      {
          $("#hidden").show();
      }
      else
      {
          $("#hidden").hide();
      }              
  });
});
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/san6gc9c/

Comment: Thank you, sadly this does not seem to work either. See here > [link](http://truedragonblood.ucoz.com/test.html)

Comment: You have to include jquery library

Comment: Exmple add this -- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Your link has no reference to jquery library

Comment: Did you add the reference of jquery library ? I still can see error in console

Comment: What is interesting however, is when I click the "Fiddle Link" it does work on the second try not the first, but on my web browser it does not respond what so ever.

Comment: The link you gave is still missing the reference to jquery library.

Comment: [check now](http://truedragonblood.ucoz.com/test.html) I updated it so you can see it :)

Comment: Nope. It is still not there. You can press F12 and go on console block to see the error displaying missing $

Comment: It is there, I can see it when I inspect the source. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E"> and the rest of the code you provided

Comment: @manuerumx solution worked in the end. Thanks for all your help and being pantient :) Good day!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#a").click(function () {
            if ($("#a").prop("checked")) {
                $("#b").hide();
                $("#c").hide();
                $("#d").hide();
                $("#e").hide();
            } else {
                $("#b").show();
                $("#c").show();
                $("#d").show();
                $("#e").show();
            }
        });
    });
<script>
```

```html
<div><input id="a" type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input id="b" type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input id="c" type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input id="d" type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input id="e" type="checkbox"></div>
```