# html checkbox list that shows and hides links when filtered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have written code that creates a checkbox list where when i click the checkbox below my list of options i would like a link to show underneath that the user can click (show/hide) I cannot figure out why my code will not work.  If the user unchecked the box the link disappears but nothing happens when i click my check boxes. I would like to do this fix in JQuery

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <div class ="container">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="grp1" type="checkbox" value="group_1" onClick="http://google.com" />  
        <label for="grp1"> group 1 </label>    
        <div>
           <input id="grp2" type="checkbox" value="group_2" onClick="http://google.com" > 
           group_2</label>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide/show content when checkbox is checked/unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104405/how-to-hide-show-content-when-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use javascript to hide/show the wanted elements in html. There are many approaches to this. The most basic one would be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <input id="grp1" type="checkbox" value="group_1"/>
    <label for="grp1"> group 1 </label>
    <br>
    <input id="grp2" type="checkbox" value="group_2"/>
    <label for="grp2"> group_2</label>

    <!--hidden elements using css-->
    <a href="#" id="url1" style="display: none;">Link for group_1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="url2" style="display: none;">Link for group_2</a>
</div>

<script>

    //listen to the click event on the whole container
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = function (e) {

        //check every box if it's checked
        if (document.getElementById('grp1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('url1').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('url1').style.display = 'none';
        }

        if (document.getElementById('grp2').checked) {
            document.getElementById('url2').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('url2').style.display = 'none';
        }


    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you can use different approaches like creating the element in javascript then adding it to the html if you don't like the idea if existing hidden elements. You might also use loops to loop through checkbox element and simply show/hide the url accordingly. And more to make the code flexible on any number of boxes. Something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="checkBoxContainer">
    <input id="grp1" type="checkbox" value="group_1"/>
    <label for="grp1"> group 1 </label>
    <br>
    <input id="grp2" type="checkbox" value="group_2"/>
    <label for="grp2"> group_2</label>
    </div>
    <!--hidden elements using css-->
    <a href="#" id="url1" style="display: none;">Link for group_1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="url2" style="display: none;">Link for group_2</a>
</div>

<script>

    //listen to the click event on the whole container
    document.getElementById("checkBoxContainer").onclick = function (e) {
        var linkNumber = 1; //This is number of the first url element with ud url1
        var containerChildren = document.getElementById("checkBoxContainer").children;

        //loop through the children elements
        for (var i = 0; i < containerChildren.length; i++) {

            var oneChild = containerChildren[i]; //catch only one child in a variable

            //simply filter the input elements which are of type checkbox
            if(oneChild.tagName === "INPUT" && oneChild.type === "checkbox"){

                //Show or hide the url accordingly.
                if (oneChild.checked) {
                    document.getElementById('url' + linkNumber++).style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('url' + linkNumber++).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! The first approach is perfect and makes 100% sense i love the comments

Comment: @JaclynBlumenthal No problems. The second example is exactly the same but using the `for` loop in javascript to loop through the elements instead of checking one by one specially in case you have many check boxes. Glade I could help.

Comment: i was testing the show hide is great but the link does not open in a new window when i click it :(

Comment: Of course it wont in this example. The url is `#` is just dummy url there for no purpose other than looking like url :D. Change `href="#"` to another url like `href="https://stackoverflow.com/"`. If you wan the url to open in new tab or window, use `target="_blank"` attribute in the `a` tag like `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">test</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The [onclick HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) doesn't work that way. The attribute value is executed as javascript. You can make a js function to show/hide the link.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you want to try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .group-link{
                display: block;
            }
            .hidden{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jsParent">
            <label for="grp1">
                <input id="grp1" type="checkbox" value="group_1" onchange="showLink(this)"/>   group 1
            </label>
            <a class="group-link hidden jsLink" href="https://www.animalplanet.com/tv-shows/dogs-101/videos/the-doberman">Group 1 Link</a>
        </div>

        <div class="jsParent">
            <label for="grp2">
                <input id="grp2" type="checkbox" value="group_2" onchange="showLink(this)"/>  group_2
            </label>
            <a class="group-link hidden jsLink" href="https://www.animalplanet.com/tv-shows/cats-101/videos/ragdoll">Group 2Link </a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showLink(el){
                var parent = el.parentElement.parentElement;
                var linkEl = getAnchorEl(parent);
                if(linkEl){
                    if(el.checked){                     
                        linkEl.classList = linkEl.classList.value.replace('hidden', '');
                    }else{
                        linkEl.classList = linkEl.classList.value + ' hidden';
                    }
                }
            }

            function getAnchorEl(parent){
                var childrens = parent.children;
                var linkEl = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++) {
                    var childEl = childrens[i];
                    if(childEl.classList.value.indexOf('jsLink') > -1){
                        linkEl = childEl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return linkEl;
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is undoubtedly a duplicate but I am answering because I would like to help you identify issues with the code you posted.

1. I notice you have a `<div>`tag between your  tag and  tag.  Why?  This is a bit of an over simplification but as a general rule never put anything between your `<html>` and `<head>` tag and only place `<div>` tags inside your `<body>` tag.  Also be mindful of how you nest your elements.  That  tag starts after  and before .
2. Even if that were correct placement you close the  before you close your div arbitrarily in the middle of your body tag.  you should never have

   `<div>
   <p>
   </div>
   </p>`

Instead it should look like this

```
<div>
   <p>
   </p>
</div>
```

3. In your onClick attribute you have a random URL.  That will not open a new window.  You new too put some javascript in there.

`<input onClick="window.open('http://google.com')">`

4. Also your second label tag does not have an opening, just a `</label>` close tag

#### To answer your question - I suggest you look at the jQuery toggle function.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="displayLink" />
<a href="http://google.com" id="googleLink" style="display:hidden;">Google</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#displayLink").click(function(){
        $("#googleLink").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

As a general rule you should favor event handlers (such as the `$("").click()` posted above) to handle events (like clicking) as opposed to html attributes such as onClick.